# To clear drawing in drawRect shape-layer drawing

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, drawrect

To save time for anyone googling here, I incorrectly thought that `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` would **also clear any layers added in drawRect**.  It does not.

Of course as Matt has explained, you should certainly only draw the ordinary way in drawRect, and then `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` works correctly. Example,

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
    // clearsContextBeforeDrawing works perfectly here as normal
    // don't add any layers in here :)

    let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:rect)
    mainColor.setFill()
    dotPath.fill()
    let ins:CGFloat = ( ringThickness / 2 )
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectInset(rect,ins,ins) )
    circlePath.lineWidth = ringThickness
    ringColor.setStroke()
    circlePath.stroke()
    }
```

---

Here's a poor way to draw in `drawRect`

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:rect)
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    circle.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circle.fillColor = someColor.CGColor
    layer.addSublayer(circle)

    ... and a few more layers like ...
    blah.fillColor = someColor.CGColor
    layer.addSublayer(blah)
    }
```

But how to clear before drawing?

Setting `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` does nothing.

The only way I can clear is by removing all the layers:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
    // first remove all layers...
    if let sublayers = layer.sublayers {
        for layer in sublayers {
            if layer.isKindOfClass(CAShapeLayer) //(essential)
                { layer.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        }
    }
    ...
    }
```

Is there a better way to clear the "layer" drawing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here's a typical way to draw in drawRect

No, it isn't. It's totally atypical — and totally wrong.

The only thing you should be doing in `drawRect` is drawing into the current context. For example:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:rect)
circlePath.stroke() // draws into the current context
```

But *your* code is about something else entirely: you're creating a bunch of *additional layers*. And that's exactly what's wrong with it, and why you're left scratching your head about the way things seems to behave. If you were doing the correct thing in `drawRect`, you'd find that indeed whenever it is called, the drawing in the view *is* cleared. *Your* drawing in your view is not being cleared because you have *no* drawing in your view. Everything is in these extra layers.

So, start over. Learn to use `drawRect` correctly. Either draw directly into the current context, or put your layer-management code elsewhere; but don't combine them by doing your layer-management in `drawRect`.

Comment: That's a way too open question. I have no notion what your overall goal is.

Comment: Anyway I totally get it - awesome.  Of course I should have been drawing in to the current context.  And then indeed `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` does work - yay!  So my confusion was that I thought `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` would also "clear layers" if you see what I mean. You've set me straight  :)  Nice...